# Symfony2 form types entity no pre load

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm building a webshop with > 40k products. Those products are stored in a MySQL table (table is generated which Symfony 2 console and Doctrine 2).

I have an purchase order system and created a form.

[table purchase_orders]

[table purchase_order_rows] (fk purchase_order_id and fk product_id)

[table products] (products (RAM modules which a lot of properties) (fk brand_id)

[table product_brands]

**PurchaseOrderType.php**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('customer', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyShop\Bundle\CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('purchaseOrderStatus', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderStatus',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('date')
        ->add('reference')
        ->add('comments')
        ->add('purchaseOrderRows', 'collection', [
            'type' => new PurchaseOrderRowType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ])
    ;
}
```

**PurchaseOrderRowType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('purchaseOrder', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('ram', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyShop\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Ram',
            'multiple' => false,
        ))
        ->add('purchaseOrderRowStatus', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderRowStatus',
            'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('description')
        ->add('count')
        ->add('startDate')
        ->add('endDate')
        ->add('amount')
        ->add('taxAmount')
        ->add('discountAmount')
    ;
}
```

When I'm generating the form with Doctrine it loads ALL the rows from the products table which leads to a very slow / non loadable web page.
How can I manage to not pre load all those products? Each product has a unique bar code which is known by the user and the database. The user just needs to enter the bar code instead of selecting the product from a dropdown list.

I have been experimenting with adding the key query_builder to the ->add('ram', 'entity' but this did not lead to a solution, I got stuck...

Also adding a new purchase order costs more than 30 seconds! I suspect this issue causes that as well.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I can see is creating a [DataTransformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) which transforms barcode to product entity and v.v. [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#using-transformers-in-a-custom-field-type) is the almost ready example which you can change a little and use it, optionally you can add some jquery plugin (such as autocomplete) to that textfield for more usability.

Comment: This option seems to work, still working on it. I'll let you know if it worked. I think I'm going to compare it with the other answer and find out which one is faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and this is the solution we came up with:

You should consider creating a **final class** ProductForChoice, with the EntityManager as a dependency and a single **invoke** method:

```
/**
* Class ProductForChoice
*/
final class ProductForChoice 
{

    /** @var EntityManager */
    protected $entityManager;

    function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function invoke()
    {
        $dql = "
            SELECT product.id, product.barCode as bar_code
            FROM Entity/Product as product

        ";
        $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery($dql);

        $results =  $query->useResultCache(true, 300)->getArrayResult();

        $ret = [];

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $ret[$result['id']] = $result['bar_code'];
        }

        return $ret;

    }

}
```

then after you made sure tho **register this class as as service** you can make use of it inside you abstract type in this fashion:

```
 ->add('product', 'filter_choice', [
            'required' => false,
            'choices' => $this->ProductForChoiceAsService->invoke(),
            'label' => 'Products',
        ]);
```

make note that, in this example a *filter_choice* is present and not an *entity*.

As a side note, if you want to keep your abstract type, dependecy-clean you may want to pass the *ProductForChoiceAsService*
 inside the form **options** instead of using the __constructor, your call.

---

To even more help the user in his quest consider adopting 
[Choosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), it's a very hany tool to turn multi-select into search-like inputbox.

Hope it helps,
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have chosen for the answer above, because it seems more "native" and loads faster.